# Remove certain post data after submit has been initailized

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to filter $_POST form data after submit has been initialized but before it sends the data to processing page?

The way I imagine the process:
Submit -> Collect $_POST data -> Send Data

What I want to do:
Submit -> Collect $_POST data -> Remove certain elements -> Send Data

So that the processing page doesn't have to be altered to filter out the elements that are not meant to be received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you can, in JS/JQuery you can collect the form data, manipulate them as needed and send them back to the processing page...

However I don't get why you would do something like that client-side?

if the purpose is to avoid sending all the fields, then remove them from form data before serializing the data.

to accomplish that you can use something like this

```
$('#form').find('input[name!=exclude]').serialize();
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: You're right, I can get JS to act as a middleman and trigger submission after, thanks. Edit: also as to why I can't use latter method, it's multiple input file with ability to remove specific elements without unsetting the whole input box, i.e. still send the data, but prevent it from reaching processing page and I need the entire form data to be sent in a single submission, because processing page. I may still be too inexperienced, but I'm not sure how to weave php and js together like that (Ajax doesn't cut it).

Comment: Glad it helped. Ajax is the way of communication... with PHP you can simply ignore sent $_POST fields and do nothing with them...

Comment: Yep, usually would go with ajax, but it needs to be compatible with multiple processing pages, sigh... And this quickfix is specifically for multiple file inputs where I may need one file but not all of them. Thanks for the help